# So I've installed FirebugForDrupal (updated)

Tags: debugging

I installed the browser plug in and module in drupal. On this (development environment) I gave authenticated users access to the 'Access Firebug Debug' permission. Site Admin has access to that and 'Execute Firebug PHP'.

Browser/Client

- Firefox 17.0.1
- Ubuntu 11.10
- Firebug 1.11.0
- DrupalForFirebug <del>0.0.8</del> 2.0
- Logged in as User 1

Server (development box)

- Drupal 6.25
- Redhat 5.8
- PHP 5.3.3

### **UPDATE:**

Just this morning DfFB released it's 2.0 version. I spun up the DfFB module again, ran cron, and cleared cache. In the source code of my page, I can now see `<div>`'s  with class names such as `drupalforfirebug_general` and `drupalforfirebug_sql`. So it appears that information is binging handed to the browser from Drupal.

[image]

### **UPDATE 2:**

I switched to DfFB 2.0a and this what I see.

[image]

Is this what I'm supposed to see?

Comment: Are you actually logging anything?  FWIW, that module has caused me nothing but grief.  Not sure if recent versions are any better that the last time I used it.

Comment: Should I give up and go xDebug?

Comment: I can echo what @MPD said, that module is not good for one's sanity. If xDebug is an option, definitely go for that

Comment: I'm old school.  I just stare at code and debug with print as needed.

Comment: Well 2.0 was *just* released today https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/drupal-for-firebug/versions/?page=1#version-2.0 Trying this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal variable/object you have in the pic could be had by just typing `console.log(Drupal)` on the console tab in FireBug. It's the Drupal JavaScript object that's recommended to be extended. eg if you run `console.log(Drupal.behaviors)` you'll see all the JavaScript functions that get called by Drupal on page load.

Anything specific you're trying to debug?

Just to make sure you've seen:

http://drupal.org/project/devel

http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

http://drupal.org/project/search_krumo

Comment: I adore the devel_* modules and use them often. I am was trying to debug theme preprocess function using print_r() and dsm(). However, I'm running out of memory when I do so. I'm marking this correct (and upvoting this and kiamlaluno's response) because the work around is to set a variable and analyze it in devel_themer variable tree.

Comment: FYI There's dsm is now `dpm($var, 'optional string')`, http://api.drupal.org/api/function/dpm/7 . Also to prevent the memory issue, you could get a list of keys, php `dpm(array_keys($var))` and then `dpm` that specific key  `dpm($var['key'])`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the extension is [not compatible with Firefox 14](http://drupal.org/node/1691908). The issue report has been opened on July 19, 2012, and it still is open.

The last comments from one of the co-maintainers of the module say:

> unfourtunatly no, currently the new (from the ground up) plugin registers itself with firebug and firefox; it displays the drupal tabs and subtabs. But it doesn't gather the data from the drupalforfirebug drupal module yet.
>
> Once it is ready I will package it as an xpi and allow it to be downloaded from bitbucket while mozilla reviews the update. I should be done sometime this week.

> So now the code on bitbucket is functional. I wouldn't call it testable -- still hanging around pre-alpha.
>
> Before I we call it testable I need to do two things.
>
> 1. Further abstract the connection between the Drupal Module and the Firefox Module. Right now the presentation layer calls the connector that returns the content directly. However, once I abstract that connection to an API call layer then changes to the API will be less problematic for Firefox plugin to deal with.
> 2. Remove the dependency on jQuery for the plugin. Currently the plugin loads jQuery to deal with a couple of UI niceties.<-- this is what is blocking the release.
>
> By all means though, If you know how to install from code a firefox plugin then please do so. It works just like the old one for the time being.

Comment: Speaking of timing... DfFB 2.0 was released this morning. I'm putting any notes in the update above while testing today.